# R commas and count issue in string

Tags: r, string

Hope someone can help and already thanks who will. Hi have my dataframe that looks as follow:

```
V1                     
A4 B1 C2    E3   T5
B3     R4     W2 E3
```

I have words divided by spaces, and is not nice to see it this way, therefore I am trying to do 2 things: 1) separate them by comma, but the number of spaces between words is not always the same and if I use gsub seems not to solve the issue, if I do

```
x$V1=gsub(" ",",",x$V1)
```

I get:

```
V1                     
A4,B1,C2,,,,E3,,,,T5
B3,,,R4,,,,W2,E3
```

Then problem number 2) I want a V2 column with the number of values, but using

```
x$V2 = length(strsplit(x$V1, ",")
```

is not helping :(
My desired output is:

```
V1              V2                 
A4,B1,C2,E3,T5  5
B3,R4,W2,E3     4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution in `base R`:

```r
df$V1 = gsub("\\s+",",",df$V1)

df$V2 <-  1 + lengths(regmatches(df$V1, gregexpr(",", df$V1)))
df

#>               V1 V2
#> 1 A4,B1,C2,E3,T5  5
#> 2    B3,R4,W2,E3  4
```

---

Another possible solution, based on `stringr`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(V1 = str_replace_all(V1, "\\s+", ","), V2 = str_count(V1, ",") + 1)

#>               V1 V2
#> 1 A4,B1,C2,E3,T5  5
#> 2    B3,R4,W2,E3  4
```

Comment: thanks, unfortunately is not changing anything :(

Comment: Oh no wait, was me typing incorrectly! seems like is working!

Comment: I have added another solution in base R.